# c++ load image to dialog MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

In MFC, I want to load image to dialog window, picture control in C++ I use these methods:

```
void diaalo::OnBnClickedOk()
{

    if(access("BMP",0))
    {
        MessageBox(L"Отсутствует папка BMP,\nгде должны находится файлы *.bmp\nдля работы с картинками \n",L"Внимание!",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        return;
    }

    if(access("BMP\\GAZ.bmp",0))
    {
        MessageBox(L"В папке BMP отсутствует файл GAZ.bmp",L"Внимание!",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        return;
    }

    HBITMAP startBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"BMP\\GAZ.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    if (!startBitmap)
    {
        MessageBox(L"В папке BMP ошибочная структура файла GAZ.bmp", L"Внимание!",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        AfxMessageBox(L"111");
        return;
    }

    st1->SetBitmap(startBitmap);

    AfxMessageBox(L"222");
}
```

There is my program, 11mb zip:
http://ge.tt/1hkPdLe/v/0?c

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What styles have been used when you created your static control `st1`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type of the static control IDC_STATIC1 must be "Bitmap" instead of "Frame".

[image]